# terraform script for configuring SSO of an application in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform-provider-azure

We are trying to automate the process of on-boarding Enterprise (non-gallery) application in Azure AD using Terraform. Couldn't find any specific script for on-boarding SAML based application in Azure AD using Terraform. So,  we have tried below script

```
resource "azuread_application" "test_app01" {
    display_name = "Test_App"
    homepage = "http://example.com/"
    identifier_uris = [ "https://example.com/saml" ]
    reply_urls = [ "https://example.com/saml" ]
    available_to_other_tenants = false
}
```

however, this script creates an application registration only. There we can't configure SSO.
Can you please help me with any reference or terraform script using which we can on-board SAML applications in Azure AD.

Comment: In my experience, we need to configure SSO in enterprise application. So you should create the enterprise application as well by using `azuread_service_principal`: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/service_principal. But I'm not sure if we can configure SSO in it because that, in Azure portal we need to create the application under Enterprise Applications rather than App Registration to create an enterprise app which supports SSO. But anyway, you can have a try.

Comment: Hi @AllenWu, thanks for your reply. The link you shared that is used for application registration. It creates an application under app registration but for this there are no options to do SSO configuration in portal. What I'm looking for is to do onboard and application as enterprise application and configure SSO using terraform script. Do you have any reference for the same?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no option to enable SSO in azuread_service_principal. I think calling AZ CLI command as a local provisioner can work for you:

az ad app update --id $APP_ID --set samlMetadataUrl=https://mysaml

Comment: If so, I think terraform may unable to implement it. Try other methods like the Az cli command suggested by @adp.